# Windows NFS file share mounted on ubuntu is read only

Tags: linux, nfs

I have created an NFS file share on windows server 2016 configured as follows:
[image: nfs config]

I have then set the permissions to allow full read-write access:[image: permissions]

And I have then updated the security to ensure every file in the directory e:\docker\volumes can be modified by anonymous users:

[image: ntfs permissions]

On my ubuntu machine I'm mounting the file share as follows:

`sudo mount 192.168.1.10:/dockervolumes /mnt/dockervolumes -o rw`

which works fine. I can view documents in there without issue, and all files have the following permissions

[image]

However creating files gives the following:

`ross@dar-docker-02:/mnt/dockervolumes/travis$ sudo touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied`

And making directories:

`ross@dar-docker-02:/mnt/dockervolumes/travis$ sudo mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Input/output error`

Why are the shares read only?!